# (Leetcode) Longest consecutive sequence in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-consecutive-sequence/submissions/) -

> *Given an unsorted array of integers, find the length of the longest
>   consecutive elements' sequence.*
>
> *Your algorithm should run in \$O(n)\$ complexity.*
>
> ***Example -***
>
> ```
> Input: [100, 4, 200, 1, 3, 2]
> Output: 4
>
> # Explanation: The longest consecutive elements sequence is [1, 2, 3, 4]. Therefore its length is 4.
> ```

Here is my solution to this challenge -

```
def longestConsecutive(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: int
    """
    if not nums:
        return 0

    nums = list(dict.fromkeys(nums))
    nums.sort()
    count = 1
    longest_streak = []

    for index, value in enumerate(nums):
        if index + 1 >= len(nums):
            break

        if nums[index + 1] == value + 1:
            count += 1
            longest_streak.append(count)
        else:
            count = 1

    if not longest_streak:
        return count

    return max(longest_streak)
```

Here is my Leetcode result -

> [image]

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program faster and more efficient.

**NOTE** - Though my solution got accepted, I really have no idea about the time complexity of my program. Maybe someone could cover that too?

Comment: Isn't nums.sort() O(n*logn)?

Comment: It is? Honestly, I don't really know why. Could you include this in an answer?

Comment: @Justin It is, as Python uses the [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Comment: @Justin you can just check the Solution that is provided [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-consecutive-sequence/solution/) . It has a good explanation for three cases: O(n^2), O(n*logn) and O(n). Yours is the second one, and you can see how to do it in O(n) there. You can also check out the Discussions!

Comment: Thanks, @a_faulty_star. I will definitely have a look. Seems like the best thing to do. Thanks again!